# How to use ITaskbarList3.RegisterTab to show an image in a tab inside the taskbar flyout?

Tags: c#, winforms

My code is mostly from [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net). I read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3). I also tried to find the Windows SDK samples directory for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663597(v=vs.85).aspx) but I did not find it on my computer, and the download link of this sample is dead.

The problem is that the tab is registered but in the taskbar preview there is no image, although the window is activated and visible (not minimized).

## Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

## Source code 1

### Designer

Just a Form and a Button inside it.

### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        TaskbarProgress.MyTaskbarInstance.RegisterTab(button1.Handle, Handle);
        TaskbarProgress.MyTaskbarInstance.SetTabOrder(button1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

### TaskbarProgress.cs

```
public static class TaskbarProgress
{
    public enum THUMBBUTTONMASK
    {
        THB_BITMAP = 0x1,
        THB_ICON = 0x2,
        THB_TOOLTIP = 0x4,
        THB_FLAGS = 0x8
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct THUMBBUTTON
    {
        public THUMBBUTTONMASK dwMask;
        public uint iId;
        public uint iBitmap;
        public IntPtr hIcon;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 259)]
        public string szTip;

        public THUMBBUTTONFLAGS dwFlags;
    }

    public enum THUMBBUTTONFLAGS
    {
        THBF_ENABLED = 0,
        THBF_DISABLED = 0x1,
        THBF_DISMISSONCLICK = 0x2,
        THBF_NOBACKGROUND = 0x4,
        THBF_HIDDEN = 0x8,
        THBF_NONINTERACTIVE = 0x10
    }

    public enum TBPFLAG
    {
        TBPF_NOPROGRESS = 0,
        TBPF_INDETERMINATE = 0x1,
        TBPF_NORMAL = 0x2,
        TBPF_ERROR = 0x4,
        TBPF_PAUSED = 0x8
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public Int32 left;
        public Int32 top;
        public Int32 right;
        public Int32 bottom;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extends ITaskbarList2 by exposing methods that support the unified launching and switching taskbar button
    /// functionality added in Windows 7. This functionality includes thumbnail representations and switch
    /// targets based on individual tabs in a tabbed application, thumbnail toolbars, notification and
    /// status overlays, and progress indicators.
    /// </summary>
    [ComImport,
     Guid("ea1afb91-9e28-4b86-90e9-9e9f8a5eefaf"),
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ITaskbarList3
    {
        // ITaskbarList

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the taskbar list object. This method must be called before any other ITaskbarList methods can be called.
        /// </summary>
        void HrInit();

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds an item to the taskbar.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be added to the taskbar.</param>
        void AddTab(IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes an item from the taskbar.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be deleted from the taskbar.</param>
        void DeleteTab(IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Activates an item on the taskbar. The window is not actually activated; the window's item on the taskbar is merely displayed as active.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window on the taskbar to be displayed as active.</param>
        void ActivateTab(IntPtr hWnd);

        /// <summary>
        /// Marks a taskbar item as active but does not visually activate it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window to be marked as active.</param>
        void SetActiveAlt(IntPtr hWnd);

        // ITaskbarList2

        /// <summary>
        /// Marks a window as full-screen
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd"></param>
        /// <param name="fFullscreen"></param>
        void MarkFullscreenWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int fFullscreen);

        /// <summary>
        /// Displays or updates a progress bar hosted in a taskbar button to show the specific percentage
        /// completed of the full operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle of the window whose associated taskbar button is being used as
        /// a progress indicator.</param>
        /// <param name="ullCompleted">An application-defined value that indicates the proportion of the
        /// operation that has been completed at the time the method is called.</param>
        /// <param name="ullTotal">An application-defined value that specifies the value ullCompleted will
        /// have when the operation is complete.</param>
        void SetProgressValue(IntPtr hWnd, ulong ullCompleted, ulong ullTotal);

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the type and state of the progress indicator displayed on a taskbar button.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle of the window in which the progress of an operation is being
        /// shown. This window's associated taskbar button will display the progress bar.</param>
        /// <param name="tbpFlags">Flags that control the current state of the progress button. Specify
        /// only one of the following flags; all states are mutually exclusive of all others.</param>
        void SetProgressState(IntPtr hWnd, TBPFLAG tbpFlags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Informs the taskbar that a new tab or document thumbnail has been provided for display in an
        /// application's taskbar group flyout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWndTab">Handle of the tab or document window. This value is required and cannot
        /// be NULL.</param>
        /// <param name="hWndMDI">Handle of the application's main window. This value tells the taskbar
        /// which application's preview group to attach the new thumbnail to. This value is required and
        /// cannot be NULL.</param>
        void RegisterTab(IntPtr hWndTab, IntPtr hWndMDI);

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes a thumbnail from an application's preview group when that tab or document is closed in the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWndTab">The handle of the tab window whose thumbnail is being removed. This is the same
        /// value with which the thumbnail was registered as part the group through ITaskbarList3::RegisterTab.
        /// This value is required and cannot be NULL.</param>
        void UnregisterTab(IntPtr hWndTab);

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts a new thumbnail into a tabbed-document interface (TDI) or multiple-document interface
        /// (MDI) application's group flyout or moves an existing thumbnail to a new position in the
        /// application's group.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWndTab">The handle of the tab window whose thumbnail is being placed. This value
        /// is required, must already be registered through ITaskbarList3::RegisterTab, and cannot be NULL.</param>
        /// <param name="hWndInsertBefore">The handle of the tab window whose thumbnail that hwndTab is
        /// inserted to the left of. This handle must already be registered through ITaskbarList3::RegisterTab.
        /// If this value is NULL, the new thumbnail is added to the end of the list.</param>
        void SetTabOrder(IntPtr hWndTab, IntPtr hWndInsertBefore);

        /// <summary>
        /// Informs the taskbar that a tab or document window has been made the active window.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWndTab">Handle of the active tab window. This handle must already be registered
        /// through ITaskbarList3::RegisterTab. This value can be NULL if no tab is active.</param>
        /// <param name="hWndMDI">Handle of the application's main window. This value tells the taskbar
        /// which group the thumbnail is a member of. This value is required and cannot be NULL.</param>
        /// <param name="tbatFlags">None, one, or both of the following values that specify a thumbnail
        /// and peek view to use in place of a representation of the specific tab or document.</param>
        void SetTabActive(IntPtr hWndTab, IntPtr hWndMDI, UInt32 tbatFlags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a thumbnail toolbar with a specified set of buttons to the thumbnail image of a window in a
        /// taskbar button flyout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle of the window whose thumbnail representation will receive the toolbar.
        /// This handle must belong to the calling process.</param>
        /// <param name="cButtons">The number of buttons defined in the array pointed to by pButton. The maximum
        /// number of buttons allowed is 7.</param>
        /// <param name="pButton">A pointer to an array of THUMBBUTTON structures. Each THUMBBUTTON defines an
        /// individual button to be added to the toolbar. Buttons cannot be added or deleted later, so this must
        /// be the full defined set. Buttons also cannot be reordered, so their order in the array, which is the
        /// order in which they are displayed left to right, will be their permanent order.</param>
        void ThumbBarAddButtons(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            uint cButtons,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] THUMBBUTTON[] pButton);

        void ThumbBarUpdateButtons(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            uint cButtons,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] THUMBBUTTON[] pButton);

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies an image list that contains button images for a toolbar embedded in a thumbnail image of a
        /// window in a taskbar button flyout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle of the window whose thumbnail representation contains the toolbar to be
        /// updated. This handle must belong to the calling process.</param>
        /// <param name="himl">The handle of the image list that contains all button images to be used in the toolbar.</param>
        void ThumbBarSetImageList(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr himl);

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies an overlay to a taskbar button to indicate application status or a notification to the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle of the window whose associated taskbar button receives the overlay.
        /// This handle must belong to a calling process associated with the button's application and must be
        /// a valid HWND or the call is ignored.</param>
        /// <param name="hIcon">The handle of an icon to use as the overlay. This should be a small icon,
        /// measuring 16x16 pixels at 96 dots per inch (dpi). If an overlay icon is already applied to the
        /// taskbar button, that existing overlay is replaced.</param>
        /// <param name="pszDescription">A pointer to a string that provides an alt text version of the
        /// information conveyed by the overlay, for accessibility purposes.</param>
        void SetOverlayIcon(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hIcon, string pszDescription);

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies or updates the text of the tooltip that is displayed when the mouse pointer rests on an
        /// individual preview thumbnail in a taskbar button flyout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle to the window whose thumbnail displays the tooltip. This handle must
        /// belong to the calling process.</param>
        /// <param name="pszTip">The pointer to the text to be displayed in the tooltip. This value can be NULL,
        /// in which case the title of the window specified by hwnd is used as the tooltip.</param>
        void SetThumbnailTooltip(IntPtr hWnd, string pszTip);

        /// <summary>
        /// Selects a portion of a window's client area to display as that window's thumbnail in the taskbar.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle to a window represented in the taskbar.</param>
        /// <param name="prcClip">A pointer to a RECT structure that specifies a selection within the window's
        /// client area, relative to the upper-left corner of that client area. To clear a clip that is already
        /// in place and return to the default display of the thumbnail, set this parameter to NULL.</param>
        void SetThumbnailClip(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr prcClip);
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    private class TaskbarInstance
    {
    }

    internal static ITaskbarList3 MyTaskbarInstance = (ITaskbarList3)new TaskbarInstance();
    private static bool taskbarSupported =
        Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(6, 1);

    public static void SetState(IntPtr windowHandle, TBPFLAG taskbarState)
    {
        if (taskbarSupported)
        {
            MyTaskbarInstance.SetProgressState(windowHandle, taskbarState);
        }
    }

    public static void SetValue(IntPtr windowHandle, double progressValue, double progressMax)
    {
        if (taskbarSupported)
        {
            // * 100 is for better visual detail of progress
            MyTaskbarInstance.SetProgressValue(
                windowHandle,
                (ulong)(progressValue * 100),
                (ulong)(progressMax * 100));
        }
    }
}
```

## Source code 2

I also tried with this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    TaskbarProgress.MyTaskbarInstance.RegisterTab(button1.Handle, Handle);
    TaskbarProgress.MyTaskbarInstance.SetTabOrder(button1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);

    var rr = button1.ClientRectangle;

    var r = new TaskbarProgress.RECT()
    {
        left = rr.Left,
        top = rr.Top,
        right = rr.Right,
        bottom = rr.Bottom
    };

    IntPtr p = StructToPtr(r);

    TaskbarProgress.MyTaskbarInstance.SetThumbnailClip(button1.Handle, p);

    FreePtr(p);
}

internal static IntPtr StructToPtr(object obj)
{
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(obj));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
    return ptr;
}

internal static void FreePtr(IntPtr p)
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
}
```

The result is the same.